# An object is being double deallocated unintentionally?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nszombie

I have a tab bar application where in one tab bar, there are 7 separate UISwitch instances. When I run the application and go to the tab bar with the switches, I then call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then I call

```
[self presentModalViewController:myController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I return to the same tab bar with the 7 `UISwitch`es and I touch one of them, changing the state, the app crashes. So I enabled `NSZombie` objects and ran the app again and this time when it crashed, it gave the error message

[UICGColor retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x9ace8a0

This means that the object was double deallocated, and I obviously didn't try doing this. So, I did some research and found that I could find the line(s) of code that cause it to double deallocate by profiling the app with an `NSZombie` template, using the Xcode built-in instruments. I then intentionally caused the app to crash, and the I received this.
[image]

I can clearly see that my ChessTimer library is releasing the object one too many times, causing it to double deallocate. So, I next looked at the exact line(s) of code that are doing this and found this[image]

I can see the lines of code now that are directly causing the problem. When I remove them, the app runs fine. The problem, however, is that these lines of code are an important design element in my app that I must keep. I don't even know why these lines of code are causing the app to deallocate that object again. How can I either neutralize this deallocation or find another workaround? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you calling dismissViewController? Have you presented something at that point?

Comment: Yes, that is confusing. What do you mean by "then look at the tab bar controller"? How can you look at it after you've just presented a view controller?

Comment: Sorry let me try re-explaining this because my previous attempt was horrible. So, when I run the app, I initially present the tab bar view controller. Then, I go to my tab bar with the UISwitches and change the state of one or two from on to off. Then, I dismiss the tab bar view controller. After that, I present the same tab bar view controller. When I change the value of one of the switches now, then the application crashes, displaying all of the images/error messages that I showed above.

Comment: Are you really presenting the "same" tab bar controller? You're keeping a reference to it and using that rather than creating a new instance?

Comment: Sorry I meant a new instance of the tab bar controller. Any advice?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see why this would happen. If you're presenting a newly instantiated tab bar controller, it seems like it should behave the same way as it did the first time. You should show some more code. Where are you presenting and dismissing from?

Comment: What are `switch1`, `switch2`, `switch3`, etc.? I mean, how are they declared? Strong/weak properties, instance variables?

Comment: @user1626438 Well as there no obvious over-relase I can see why don't you try to fix under-release issue when you allocate the colors but never release them ? Use `+ (UIColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage *)image` as it returns autoreleased colors or create the colors with `alloc, initWithPatternImage` and release them after switches are customised.